# Calculating the Value of Pi in Processing

Tags: java, processing

Processing is an environment that makes use of Java. I am trying to to use the Monte Carlo method to calculate the value of Pi. I am trying to create a dartboard (a circle within a square), and return "Yes" whenever the randomly selected point is selected within the circle.

Processing uses a coordinate system where the top left corner is the origin, rightwards is the positive x-axis, and downwards is the *positive* y-axis.

Here's my code:

```
float circleX;
float circleY;
float r;

void setup() {
  size(360, 360);
  circleX = 50;
  circleY = 50;
  frameRate(0.5);
}

void draw() {
  background(50);
  fill(255);
  stroke(255);
  fill(100);
  ellipse(180, 180, 360, 360);
  ellipse(circleX, circleY, 10, 10);
  circleX = random(360);
  circleY = random(360);

  r = (circleX-180)*(circleX-180) + (180-circleY)*(180-circleY);

  if (r < 32400) {

    print("Yes! ");

  }
}
```

However, on many instances, points inside the circle do not return "Yes," and points outside the circle do return "Yes." Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: What is the second circle (`ellipse(circleX, circleY, 10, 10);`)? It is drawn before the values for `circleX` and `circleY` get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to swap the lines generating the random coordinates and drawing it:

```
  // Generate new random coordinates
  circleX = random(360);
  circleY = random(360);
  // Draw circle at those coordinates
  ellipse(circleX, circleY, 10, 10);

  // Check whether the coordinates are withing the big circle
  r = (circleX-180)*(circleX-180) + (180-circleY)*(180-circleY);
```

The way you do it, the circle is drawn before you generate new coordinates, which you then check.

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much! Makes a lot of sense, now.

Comment: Hi! I had one quick question.

I added the functionality to plot the current value of pi onto a graph. However, using xCoordinate = xCoordinate + 1 as the number of random numbers increases to plot the graph has proven to be a very limited method due to the finite horizontal space. How can I make the graph such that the newest value is always added to a constant xCoordinate, with the previous values shifting backwards as the number of random points increases? If this isn't very clear, I will send you my current code, which may help you understand my question better. Thanks once again.

Comment: Create new question for that. Comments are too limited for a meaningful answer or question. But DON'T edit this one, create a new question. One question per question ;)

Comment: Done. Kindly have a look.